# Biased estimator problem where there is no convergence

Tags: probability-distributions, parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood

it's been a while since I've done statistics, but I am working on a problem where I have the following pdf:
$$f(x;\lambda) =\cfrac{\lambda}{x^{1+\lambda}} \;\;\; 1 \leq x < \infty, \;\;\; \lambda > 0$$

I want to determine if the sample mean estimator $\widehat{\lambda} = E(X) $ is a biased estimator of $\lambda$ or not.

$$E(X) = \int_{1}^{\infty} \cfrac{x\lambda}{x^{1+\lambda}}dx = \int_{1}^{\infty} \cfrac{\lambda}{x^{\lambda}}dx $$

which does not converge for $\lambda <1$. Since $\lambda>0$, is it fair to say this is a biased estimator, from this result alone, or have I made some glaringly obvious mistake here?

For $\lambda > 1$, $E(X) = \cfrac{\lambda}{\lambda-1} \neq \lambda$ it is easy to see, but I guess I was just a little unsure because my integral didn't converge over a set of values my parameter is defined over, and I've never encountered that before.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you're right that $\lambda$ should be $>1$. Note that when $\lambda=2$ it does equal $E(X)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample mean is not equal to $E(X)$ or that integral. It is $\sum X_i / n$. 
In cases where [Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) is applicable, the expected value of the sample mean of $X$ is equal is to the expected value of $X$.

The expected value of your estimator, i.e. the sample mean, is $\cfrac{\lambda}{\lambda-1}$ in your example when $\lambda > 1$ , and
it is $\infty$ in your example when $\lambda \leq 1$.

The definition of bias is: $\text{Bias}(\hat\lambda, \lambda) =  \mathsf{E}[ \hat\lambda] - \lambda $

Consider both cases separately: If $\lambda \leq 1$ or $\lambda > 1$. 
In the first case, $\mathsf{E}[ \hat\lambda] = \infty$, i.e.  $\text{Bias}(\hat\lambda, \lambda) \neq 0 $.
In the second case, clearly, $\text{Bias}(\hat\lambda, \lambda) \neq 0 $

In both cases, it is a biased estimator.

Comment: @Han The OP said "sample mean": Sample mean is $\sum X_i / n$, which is what I say

Comment: whoops sorry. I skipped a few steps in my explanation, but I meant to say that if we take the expectation of the sample mean estimator, we get the expected value of X. Thanks for clarifying!